# Rename files on sub-folder and upload

Tags: bash, sed, aws

Running a deployment script that removes the .html part of a file before uploading it to an S3 bucket. Currently using the following:

```
cd out/ 
for file in `ls -l *.html`; do 
    newname=`echo $file|sed 's/\.html$//g'`
    mv $file $newname
    aws2 s3 cp ./$newname s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/
done
```

This works perfectly for files in the `out/` folder, but it completely ignores, for example, `out/folder/file`.

Ideally I would be able to perform the same action (of removing the .html part of the filename) on sub-folders and pass that to my upload command.

Comment: The reason this was a oneliner is because it is part of a CICD process.

Comment: Huh? If "CICD" means "continuous integration and continuous delivery", that should have no impact on how a script is formatted. If anything, it should mean _not_ writing it as a one-line would be preferred, with comments, so that team members easily can see what it does, what failure conditions it has etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob

for pathname in out/**/*.html; do
    newname=${pathname%.html}
    mv "$pathname" "$newname"
    aws2 s3 cp "$newname" "s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/"
done
```

This takes care to

1. not parse the output of `ls` (see "[Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)")
   (your loop would additionally loop over *all the other info* that `ls -l` output (permissions, ownership, timestamps etc.), so I find it strange that you say that it work at all), and
2. properly quote variables (see "[Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)"), and
3. handle pathnames as entities and not as strings (`sed` etc. are primarily for editing lines of text; when it comes to pathnames on Unix, these may contain newlines (unlikely, but it's allowed); using a simple parameter substitution to remove a filename suffix is safer, and quicker, than calling `sed` (and `echo`) to do it), and
4. find files in any subdirectory of `out` that has filenames ending in `.html` using the `**` glob (enabled via the `globstar` shell option), and
5. not run the loop if the pattern doesn't match anything (using the `nullglob` shell option).

It additionally does not need to use `cd` as the `$pathname` and `$newname` values will include the full path from the current directory to any matched filename.

Comment: Won't this ignore the out/ directory, which holds .html files that also need to be stripped of the .html? Files are both in the out/ as well as sub-directories.

Comment: @t988GF It will not ignore any `.html` files in the `out` directory.  The `**` glob will also match inside that directory.

Comment: worked very well. Only issue I'm having is that when the upload happens, it does not include the folder the file came from (file from root/folder/file is uploaded as file, and not as folder/file) Any tips on addressing that?

Comment: @t988GF That's an issue related to how the `aws2 s3 cp` command works and how it treats pathnames. I have never used S3 and I don't really know how their "buckets" work. You could potentially try using `"s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/$newname"` as the destination path, but I don't know if that would work as I have no way of testing it.

Comment: that also fixed it. Specially aws2 s3 cp "$newname" s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/"$newname". Only issue I'm having now is that even the "out" folder is being appended to the files (aka the root folder). This work perfectly for sub-folders but, since out/ is the root folder, it would be good if it wasn't in the path that is given to $newname.

Comment: @t988GF Just strip the leading `out/` off from the destination name: `"s3://$S3_BUCKET_NAME/${newname#out/}"`. Note that the whole destination path needs to be double quoted, not just the variable substitution at the end (you have another variables, `$S3_BUCKET`, in there that also should be quoted).